# how can i insert an image having a .gif format?

Tags: android, eclipse

Can you give some projects how to insert an image like that on android?I want to add that image in my xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I display it my image?

Comment: are you planing to show animation using .gif?

Comment: nope.my picture is on .gif format.How can I insert an image having a .gif format..

Comment: its basically same as you add any picture.

Comment: even the picture is moving?

Comment: if picture is moving ( animated) the refer my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use an ImageView.  It takes all the standard formats.

Comment: can you give an example of yours?

Comment: If you need an example of something that simple, you need to reread the android tutorials.  Its pretty much a Hello World app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo_small"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

and place your image file into `res/drawable/logo.gif` (or in a resolution specific drawable directory)

Comment: What do you mean by "image is moving"?

Comment: i mean, my image is like only a jpeg file.My image is animated

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display moving GIF then there is not direct aproach, You have to try a way around, Refer bellow link for more details.

REF [GIF in Android](http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/)

OR you can load the image in a web View and display it. ( web view should be able to display the animation )

Comment: can you give me an example of that webview that can display my image?